# Manipulate file contents in Webpack

Tags: webpack

I want to manipulate file content freely in a way like below. What is the best solution?
This time I am using JSON, but I want the ability to do this with any string content. However, if a way specific to JSON is available, please also include it.

```
...
{
  use: '...content-loader',
  test: /messages\.json$/,
  function: (data) => {
    const object = JSON.parse(data)
    for(let key in object){
      object[key] = myFunction(key, object[key])
    }
    return JSON.stringify(object)
  }
},
...
```

This should be really easy but searching is returning a number of varying different solutions to unrelated answers.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a loader myself.
Example below:

```
// content-loader
const { getOptions } = require('loader-utils')

function loader (source) {
  const options = getOptions(this)
  const response = options.function(source)
  return response
}
module.exports = loader

// webpack.config.js rule in module.rules
{
  test: /messages\.json$/,
  loaders: [
    {
      loader: 'content-loader',
      options: {
        function: (data) => {
          const object = JSON.parse(data)
          for(let key in object){
            object[key] = myFunction(key, object[key])
          }
          return JSON.stringify(object)
        }
      }
    }
]}
```